# aiogram telegram bot как спрятать ссылку в кликабельное слово? Типо: *клик*

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

работаю с библиотекой aiogram в документации нашел такое:

```
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hide_link

@dp.message(Command("hidden_link"))
async def cmd_hidden_link(message: Message):
    await message.answer(
        f"{hide_link('https://telegra.ph/file/562a512448876923e28c3.png')}"
        f"Документация Telegram: *существует*\n"
        f"Пользователи: *не читают документацию*\n"
        f"Груша:"
    )
```

делаю также:

```
@dp.message(F.text == "Пополнить")
async def Popolnitt(message: types.Message):
        await message.reply(f"""{hide_link('ссылка')}Пополнить можно по ссылке:\n""")
```

и в боте выходит это:

```
<a href="ссылка">&#8203;</a>Пополнить можно по ссылке:
```

помогите пожалуйста исправить, буду очень благодарен!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `parse_mode="HTML"` для форматирования и `disable_web_page_preview=True`, чтобы ссылка была без превью

```
@dp.message(F.text == "Пополнить")
async def Popolnitt(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f'Пополнить можно <a href="https://google.com">по ссылке</a>', disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode="HTML")
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло!!

Answer (score 0):

Где ж ты также делаешь? Посмотри внимательней как указано в примере:

```
{hide_link('https://telegra.ph/file/562a512448876923e28c3.png')}
```

и у тебя как:

```
{hide_link('ссылка')}Пополнить можно по ссылке:\n"""
```

После закрывающей скобки, где указана ссылка, указывается надпись.

Вот из [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style) Telegram bot API, как должна указываться ссылка:

```
[inline URL](http://www.example.com/)
```

Comment: т.е. должно указываться так: ```f"{hide_link('ссылка')"Пополнить можно по ссылке:\n"}")```? Я новичок в этом просто, не до конца всё понимаю.

Comment: сделал также как в примере: ``` await message.answer(
        f"{hide_link('https://telegra.ph/file/562a512448876923e28c3.png')}"
        f"Документация Telegram: *существует*\n"
        f"Пользователи: *не читают документацию*\n"
        f"Груша:"
    ) ``` и всё равно с html в сообщении вылазит

Comment: Всё, разобрался, спасибо!